# Wordpress 3.5.2 dont load tinymce correct

Tags: javascript, wordpress, reference, tinymce, invalid-characters

Since last wordpress update to **3.5.2** the visual composer and tinyMCE stopped working and I get a javascript error at runtime when trying to load the editor.

`SyntaxError: Invalid character '\u0031' wp-tinymce.php:1`

post.php:1531 ReferenceError: Can't find variable: tinyMCE

post.php:1581 ReferenceError: Can't find variable: tinyMCE

load-scripts.php:194 ReferenceError: Can't find variable: tinyMCE

When i try to load tinymce.php with the code referenced from /wp-admin/post.php?post=125&action=edit

http://www.webking.se/wp-includes/js/tinymce/wp-tinymce.php?c=1&ver=358-24486

The characters look all corrupt, but if I remove the querystring 
http://www.webking.se/wp-includes/js/tinymce/wp-tinymce.php
it looks readable. Any idea what this can depend on? It worked perfect before the latest Wordpress upgrade.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding `define( 'CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false );`  to wp-config.php solved the problem.

The problem seems related to compression.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me! I added this to the config, flushed my browser cache and... POOF, it was working.